# the variable name @name has been already declared variable names must be Unique

Tags: vb.net

[This is the error Occurs on my system](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TOpYj.jpg)

this is my code Update

```
Try
        Dim conn As New SqlConnection("Data Source=HAMSE_PC\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Body;Integrated Security=True")
        cmd.Connection = conn
        conn.Open()

        Dim UpdateSQL, name, dis, username, pass As String
        name = txtname.Text
        dis = txtdiscription.Text
        username = txtusername.Text
        pass = txtpassword.Text

        UpdateSQL = "Update Users Set "
        UpdateSQL &= "FullName=@fullname,Phone=@phone,Date=@date,Discription=@dis,UserName=@user,Password=@pass "
        UpdateSQL &= "Where User_ID=@ID"



        cmd.CommandText = UpdateSQL

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fullname", name)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date", Convert.ToDateTime(txtdate.Text).Date)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dis", dis)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@user", username)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pass", pass)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@phone", Convert.ToInt32(txtphone.Text).ToString)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", Convert.ToInt32(txtid.Text).ToString)

        If txtname.Text = "" Or txtdate.Text = "" Or txtusername.Text = "" Or txtpassword.Text = "" Or txtphone.Text = "" Then
            MessageBox.Show("to update please fill the empty Columns ", "Attention")
            txtname.Focus()
        Else
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

            MsgBox("Updated")
            Dim dt As New DataTable
            Dim ds As New DataSet
            ds.Tables.Add(dt)

            Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter
            da = New SqlDataAdapter("select * from Users", conn)
            da.Fill(dt)

            UsersDataGridView.DataSource = dt.DefaultView
            txtname.Text = ""
            txtdate.Text = ""
            txtusername.Text = ""
            txtpassword.Text = ""
            txtphone.Text = ""

            ID()
        End If
        conn.Close()

    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    End Try
```

Comment: Unrelated, but you may want to [stop using `AddWithValue`](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/)

Comment: strange, where the variable fullname comes from?

Comment: a) Do not reuse DB provider objects.  Connection and Command should be created, used and disposed of.  b) Passwords should never be stored as plain text

Answer (score 1):

its because the previous commandtext in cmd(its global declared) holds value for parameter @fullname.
use

```
cmd.Parameters.Clear()
```

before specifying parameter values which clears existing parameter values in query.hope it helps.

Comment: Probably yes, you are giving a solution to its problem, but it is like hiding the dust under the carpet. You should say that there is never a valid reason to keep a command as a global object

Comment: ya thats true.but he may have some reason to keep it global.so to overcome current situation i provided best way possible according to my knowledge.even i had similar situations to keep command variable as global.

Comment: Thanks More and More Millions of Time akhil Kumar

Answer (score 0):

the following is a proof of concept to follow as a guideline. Note some code uses xml literals which may not work if using an older version of the .NET Framework along with how I use the With method to assign properties. The code is not meant to be simply dropped in but studied then apply to your code if you see fit. Note also you should always check the results of update or insert commands as shown below for success or failure. Finally using statements will close the connection and release memory for the connection and commands.

I used to commands but the other option is to clear the parameter collection as indicated by akhil kumar.

```
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Module Module1
    Public Sub Demo()
        Using conn As New SqlConnection("Data Source=HAMSE_PC\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Body;Integrated Security=True")
            Using cmd As New SqlCommand("", conn)
                cmd.CommandText =
                    <SQL>
                        UPDATE Users 
                        SET
                            FullName = @fullname,
                            Phone = @phone,
                            [Date] = @date,
                            Discription = @dis,
                            UserName = @user,
                            [Password] = @pass 
                        WHERE
                            User_ID = @ID
                    </SQL>.Value

                cmd.Parameters.Add(
                    New SqlParameter With
                    {
                        .ParameterName = "@fullname",
                        .SqlDbType = SqlDbType.NVarChar,
                        .Value = "TODO"
                    }
                )

                ' add remaining parameters

                conn.Open()

                Dim affected As Integer = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery
                If affected = 1 Then
                    ' success
                    Dim dt As New DataTable
                    Using cmdRead As New SqlCommand With {.Connection = conn, .CommandText = "select * from Users"}
                        dt.Load(cmdRead.ExecuteReader)
                        UsersDataGridView.DataSource = dt.DefaultView
                    End Using

                Else
                    ' not what we expected e.g. more than one row
                    ' was changed etc.
                End If
            End Using
        End Using
    End Sub
End Module
```